# How to block access to files that contains a specific word onhtaccess fileMatch?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm looking for a solution with htaccess to block access to files that contains the word "scheduleBackup" (case sensitive).

I tried this but it does not work :

```
<filesMatch "/scheduleBackup/i">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer :

```
<FilesMatch "_scheduleBackup_full_">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Now it works !

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<FilesMatch "/website\.com_scheduleBackup_full_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_.+?\.zip/">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

`i` means **insensitive** case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it still does not work.
For information, files I'm trying to block are like this :
**website.com_scheduleBackup_full_2015-02-19_667615a581668aecfda3445e68486362.zip**

there is maybe another solution ?

Comment: TY. Updated my htaccess but still able to get the file. (I also have website in .fr, .info. etc...)

Answer (score 0):

To block access to any file with `scheduleBackup` (ignore case) text you can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule scheduleBackup - [F,NC]
```

Comment: The htaccess in on the top main "/" folder. Files I want to block are in differents /subfolder1 /sufolder2 etc. 
This solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: This will still work irrespective of subfolders. You may have some conflicting rules below/above this rule.